# Number of times the integer that input occurs by using multiset

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program that gives out the number of times it occurs when I gave the input.
For example, 10 20 10.
Number : 10. Number of times : 2
Number : 20. Number of times : 1
But instead my result gave me
Number : 10. Number of times : 2
Number : 20. Number of times : 1
Number : 10. Number of times : 2

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void count_occurence(unordered_map<int, int>& m, vector<int>& vec)
{
    for (auto itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end(); ++itr)
    {
        ++m[*itr];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input;
    vector<int> vec;

    cout << "Eingabe der Ganzzahl : \n";
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        vec.push_back(input);
    }

    unordered_map<int, int> m;
    count_occurence(m, vec);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Das Ergebnis : \n";
    for (const auto& i : vec)
    {
        cout << "Nummer : " << i << ". Anzahl : " << m[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not iterate over the map `m` instead? And your title is misleading as you're not using `multiset` anywhere in the code you show.

Comment: And if you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or simply use an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement) you should easily see whyt you get the output you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another vector. There will be only one element of each kind in it.

```
void count_occurence(unordered_map<int, int>& m, vector<int>& vec)
{
    vector<int> order;
    for (auto itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if (m.find(*itr) == m.end())
            order.push_back(*itr);
        ++m[*itr];
    }
    vec = order;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you iterate over the vector `vec` when you print the results. And as it will contain the duplicate values you will print that value and its counter multiple times.

A simpler solution might be to iterate over the map instead:

```
for (auto const& pair : m)
{
    std::cout << "Nummer : " << pair.first << ". Anzahl : " << pair.second << '\n';
}
```